# how can i access home kit accessory controls outside apple platform

Tags: ios, iphone, homekit

I need to access Homekit accessories out of apple ecosystem.
Is it possible how can access home kit cloud database.Currently i am facing this issue how can i get the apple cloud home hub apis outside that are exposed to external applications to access